# I want edit user in input when i click button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello guys i have problem,

This is my code. when i click edit button (after create user) i want user insert to input and edit user in there. than click button "düzenle" user will change.

and this is full code's. [link goes to codepen](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/OENoew)

this is last part of my project but i cant do this. thank you for all answers.

```js
var userList = [];

var config = {
    date: {
        day: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "long",
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "2-digit"
    }
}

var generateGUID = () => {
    var s4 = () => {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

var generateRow = user => `<tr>
        <td>
        ${user.name}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.surname}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.email}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.username}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.createDate.toLocaleDateString("tr", config.date)}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>`;



$("#button").click(() => {
    let user = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        surname: $('#surname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        username: $('#username').val(),
        createDate: new Date(),
        id: generateGUID()
    };

    userList.push(user);

    let row = $(generateRow(user));

    $(row).find(".del").click(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
    });

    $(row).find(".edit").click(function () {
        $("#edit").show();
        $("#button").hide();
    });



    $('tbody').append(row);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/BVzJKR

```
var userList = [];

var config = {
    date: {
        day: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "long",
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "2-digit"
    }
}

var generateGUID = () => {
    var s4 = () => {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

var generateRow = user => `<tr data-info='${JSON.stringify(user)}' >
        <td>
        ${user.name}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.surname}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.email}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.username}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.createDate.toLocaleDateString("tr", config.date)}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>`;



$("#button").click(() => {
    let user = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        surname: $('#surname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        username: $('#username').val(),
        createDate: new Date(),
        id: generateGUID()
    };

    userList.push(user);

    let row = $(generateRow(user));

    $(row).find(".del").click(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
    });

    $(row).find(".edit").click(function () {
      console.log()
      var info = $(this).closest('tr').data('info');
      $('#name').val(info.name);
      $('#surname').val(info.surname);
      $('#email').val(info.email);
      $('#username').val(info.username);
      $('#password').val(info.password);
        $("#edit").show();
        $("#button").hide();
    });



    $('tbody').append(row);

});
```

Comment: no i didnt run code. cause its not working. i delete console.log. i dont understand.

Comment: Have you clicked on edit button? Isn't it showing content to form?

Answer (score 1):

for make each row become editable you need to indentify which 'field / td' you want allow to edit,in this code i use class to identify:

```
var generateRow = user => `<tr>
    <td class="txt">
    ${user.name}
    </td>
    <td class="txt">
    ${user.surname}
    </td>
    <td class="txt">
    ${user.email}
    </td>
    <td class="txt">
    ${user.username}
    </td>
    <td >
    ${user.createDate.toLocaleDateString("tr", config.date)}
    </td>
    <td>
        <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
        <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr>`;
```

After i identify which 'field / td' allow to be edited,i do edit with this code:

```
var activeEditedRow;
$(row).find(".edit").click(function () {
    activeEditedRow = row;
  $(row).find('td').each (function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("txt")){
      myVal = $(this).html();
      $(this).html('<input type="text" value='+myVal+'>')
      }
  });  
    $("#edit").show();
    $("#button").hide();
});

$('#edit').click(function(){      
  $(activeEditedRow).find('td').each(function() {
      myVal = $(this).find('input').val();          
      $(this).html(myVal);
  });          
})
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: this is good but another problem is i want edit user in input side i mean when i clicked  edit button user must go to input side.

Comment: what do u mean by 'input side'?you mean input inside form?

Comment: sorry for my bad english.  i want like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sy_ANQ27WfM&t=1332s

Comment: ur welcome. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.